# How to stop python from automatically converting a float number to a complex number?

Tags: python

I'm creating a function to compute Newton's method. However, the functions *f* and *df* keep returning a complex number. I am getting a type error: "can't convert complex to float" at the line where I am defining *f*.
How do I stop python from returning a complex number and not a float?

```
from cmath import cos, sin
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def Newtons_method(f, df, x0, i_max, eps_x, eps_f):

    errors = []
    conv = 0
    xk = x0
    for k in range(i_max):

        res = f(xk)
        approx_err = -1.0 * res / df(xk)
        errors.append([k, abs(approx_err), res])

        if (abs(approx_err) < eps_x) and (res < eps_f):

            array_errors = np.array(errors)
            conv = 1
            return xk, array_errors, conv

        der = df(xk)

        if der == 0:

            print("Derivative is zero")
            return None

        xk = xk + approx_err

    print("Exceeded maximum iterations")
    return None

def f(x):
    return float(x * x - 2 * x * cos(x) + cos(x) * cos(x))

def df(x):
    return float(2 * x - 2 * (cos(x) - x * sin(x)) - sin(2 * x))

x0 = 1.0
i_max = 50
eps_x = 1.0e-12
eps_f = 1.0

solution_Newton, record_Newton, flag_Newton = Newtons_method(f, df, x0, i_max, eps_x, eps_f)

x = record_Newton[:,0]
y = record_Newton[:,1]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.yscale("log")
plt.title("Newton's method")
plt.xlabel("Number of iterations")
plt.ylabel("Approximate errors")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example. Your explanation of the values for `f` etc. is not adequate for debugging. We need to see actual code. Also, it isn't clear why you think `approx_err` is the unexpected `complex` value. Did you [test that](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? Because that can't possibly be the problem here; your comparison is to `abs(approx_err)`, and `abs` called on a `complex` value will give back a `float` (you can easily test this).

Comment: I think it's the functions f and df that are returning a complex value. They're returning the values as 1.678905 +0j, for example. How do I stop that from happening?

Comment: They will definitely not do that as written, since you are *explicitly* converting to `float`. Again: try to write *one, continuous piece of code* that someone else can *copy and paste*, run *without any kind of modification*, and see *the exact problem* you describe. Make sure that it works like that, by trying it yourself first before posting.

Comment: If I copy and paste the code you have shown so far, add `from math import cos, sin`, and then try `Newtons_method(f, df, 1.0, 50, 1.0e-12, 1.0)`, I don't get any exception raised and I get back a 3-tuple. The resulting `xk` is approximately 0.739. My best guess is that either `eps_x` or `eps_f` is not what you think it is.

Comment: I removed float() and added .real at the end of the return statements for f and df so that only the real part of the complex number gets returned. My code is working now but I still don't get why f and df were returning a complex number.

Comment: Check your input, is there any complex there?

Comment: No, all of the arguments to the function are real numbers. I've added my full code.

Comment: "My code is working now but I still don't get why f and df were returning a complex number." I can guarantee you that they were not actually doing so, as shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you are using `cmath` instead of `math`:

```
>>> import cmath
>>> import math
>>> cmath.cos(0)
(1-0j)
>>> math.cos(0)
1.0
```

The help for `cmath` starts by explaining that it is for complex numbers:

> Help on built-in module cmath:
>
> NAME
> cmath
>
> DESCRIPTION
> This module provides access to mathematical functions for complex
> numbers.

If you don't want to be working with complex numbers, simply replace `cmath` with `math` and your error should go away. When I do that your code runs and produces this figure instead of spitting out a `TypeError`:
[image: results without cmath]